# scrollTo just works on the first link

Tags: php, jquery, scroll

I've got this lines of code that, when the user clicks on the link, the page should scroll down to the respective anchor.

Turns out that it only works with the first link. The others just fire this exception

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'slice' of undefined
```

Here's the code

jQuery

```
$(document).on('click','#scrollTo',function(){

                var to = $(this).attr('class');
                //alert(to);
                //This allways print the correct class name

                $(window).scrollTo('div #'+to,'1000');


            });
```

PHP

```
<ul id="source">
            <?php 
            $sourceRCS = $source->getAllSources();
            foreach($sourceRCS as $src)
            {
                echo '<li data-value="'.$src->name.'"><a href="#" id="scrollTo" class="'.$src->name.'">'.$src->name.'</a></li></a>';
            }

            ?>
    </ul>
foreach($sourceRCS as $src)
{


       echo '
    <div class="custom-label-src">
         <div id="'.$src->name.'" class="span12 label-title-src">
            '.$src->name.'
         </div>
    </div>';

}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

ID's are supposed to be unique, but you repeat #scrollTo. Try using a CSS class as your target instead.

Comment: Still the same behavior. Changed the code to this `$(document).on('click','.scrollTo',function(){
                    
                    var to = $(this).text(); 
                    //alert(to);
                    
                    $(window).scrollTo('div #'+to,'1000');
                    
                    
                });` And removed the class attibute of the link, but only the first link scrolls.

Answer (score 0):

```
var to = $(this).attr('class');
$(window).scrollTo('div #'+to,'1000');
```

You are selecting a class and assigning it to "to".  Then you take the class and convert it into an ID in the next line.

Your selector should be like this:

```
var to = $(this).attr('class');
$(window).scrollTo('div .' + to,'1000');
```

Comment: I'm not converting anything. I'm just using the content of the class

Answer (score 0):

Html Id's have to be unique. Like previously suggested, try using classes instead. Also, try capturing the event target and scrolling to it:

```
$(document).click(function(evt){
   var target = evt.target;
   $(window).scrollTo(target, 1000);
});
```

However, this will scroll to everything that a user clicks on. A better solution is to set up click event handlers on only the anchor tags that you want to scroll to:

```
$("#source a").click(function(evt){
   evt.preventDefault();
   var target = $(evt.currentTarget);
   $(window).scrollTo(target, 1000);
   // More code here...
});
```